# Why has the Miniscript for this particular Policy changed over the past few months?

Tags: script, miniscript

The "A 3-of-3 that turns into a 2-of-3 after 90 days" policy:

`thresh(3,pk(key_1),pk(key_2),pk(key_3),older(12960))`

compiled to this Miniscript a few months ago:

`thresh(3,pk(key_1),s:pk(key_2),s:pk(key_3),sdv:older(12960))`

which can be decoded to this script:

```
<key_1> OP_CHECKSIG OP_SWAP <key_2> OP_CHECKSIG OP_ADD OP_SWAP <key_3>
OP_CHECKSIG OP_ADD OP_SWAP OP_DUP OP_IF
  <a032> OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY OP_VERIFY
OP_ENDIF
OP_ADD 3 OP_EQUAL
```

Today it compiles to this Miniscript instead (note the `sln` wrapper instead of the `sdv` wrapper:

`thresh(3,pk(key_1),s:pk(key_2),s:pk(key_3),sln:older(12960))`

which can be decoded to this script:

```
<key_1> OP_CHECKSIG OP_SWAP <key_2> OP_CHECKSIG OP_ADD OP_SWAP <key_3>
OP_CHECKSIG OP_ADD OP_SWAP OP_IF
  0
OP_ELSE
  <a032> OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY OP_0NOTEQUAL
OP_ENDIF
OP_ADD 3 OP_EQUAL
```

Why has it changed?

Comment: Just a note, there is no "*the* miniscript for a policy". The compiler has a lot of freedom in determining what miniscript to compile a policy too, and in theory an improved compiler could do better than current version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thresh(3,pk(key_1),s:pk(key_2),s:pk(key_3),sdv:older(12960))` is no longer a valid Miniscript and won't successfully pass through the Miniscript analyzer on sipa's [site](https://bitcoin.sipa.be/miniscript/).

The reason for this is there was a MINIMALIF [bug](https://github.com/rust-bitcoin/rust-miniscript/blob/master/doc/security_report_2022_04_20.md) where:

> The wrapper `d` (OP_DUP OP_IF [X] OP_ENDIF) was incorrectly marked to have the `u` property. The `u` property states "When [X] is satisfied, this expression will put an exact 1 on the stack (as opposed to any nonzero value)". However, this is only true if we have a MINIMALIF consensus rule.

If you don't respect the MINIMALIF rule (only introduced with Taproot) `<3> <> <> <>` satisfies the old script without any signatures if the timelock is satisfied.

`thresh` requires the `u` type modifier which `d:` doesn't have since the bug fix so `d:` can no longer be used within a `thresh`.

Thanks to darosior for answering this on IRC.